# Will multiple GPUs allow for larger models and batch sizes when using TF2 (oibject detection API)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, object-detection-api

I am using the TF2 research object detection API with the official models from the model zoo. However, when I either try to train a large model (e.g. one of the larger Efficient net models) and/or when I want to use a large batch size (e.g. > 32) then I run out of GPU memory.

Now I am thinking of either renting some cloud GPUs or upgrading my local hardware with a second GPU. The idea is to train the TF2 models on multiple GPUs. However, before I spend the money, I would like to know whether this would even solve my problem.

So, when one trains a TF2 model (via the object detection API) on multiple GPUs, would that also "combine" their memory, so that I can train larger models and/or use larger batch sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58292482/how-to-enable-multi-gpu-training-with-tensorflow-object-detection-api) post for training using multiple GPU's. Ideally, if you use multiple GPUs, you can set a higher batch size with none to minimum changes in your code.

However, for splitting a large model across multiple GPU's, you will have to make some code changes that you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313934/is-it-possible-to-split-a-network-across-multiple-gpus-in-tensorflow#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=Splitting%20a%20large%20model%20across,code%20in%20a%20with%20tf.)

You can check out all the list of strategies for distributed training [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training)